# jar tvf output difference

Tags: list, jar

What would cause the below difference in jar tvf output?

```
bash-3.00$ jar tvf DC_Aging.jar
     0 Wed May 16 14:17:48 CDT 2012 META-INF/
    71 Wed May 16 14:17:48 CDT 2012 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
     0 Wed May 16 14:17:30 CDT 2012 com/
     0 Wed May 16 14:17:30 CDT 2012 com/perf/
     0 Wed May 16 14:17:30 CDT 2012 com/perf/sess/
     0 Wed May 16 14:17:30 CDT 2012 com/perf/sess/reports/
     0 Wed May 16 14:17:30 CDT 2012 com/perf/sess/reports/
     0 Wed May 16 14:17:30 CDT 2012 com/perf/sess/reports/business/
     0 Wed May 16 14:17:30 CDT 2012 com/perf/sess/reports/business/rules/
     0 Wed May 16 14:17:30 CDT 2012 com/perf/sess/reports/business/rules/ed/
22139 Wed May 16 14:17:36 CDT 2012 com/perf/sess/reports/business/rules/ed/DateComparisons.class
```

This is the same jar file using the same java version on the same console produces the output below. The only difference is the day on which the jar command was run. This is breaking one of our scripts.

```
bash-3.00$ jar tvf DC_Aging.jar
    25 Fri Mar 29 09:56:14 CDT 2013 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
25476 Fri Mar 29 09:52:54 CDT 2013 com/perf/sess/reports/business/rules/ed/DateComparisons.class
```

Comment: It is fairly clear that the jar files are very different. As you can see the dates and the sizes of the contained files are very different. You can check the `md5sum` of the files to see if they are the same.

Comment: Even though the jar files are different,  I want to know what is causing the output to be different. Its the same jar tvf command using the same java version. I don't care about the size

Comment: I see. I don't know the answer but would speculate that when packing a zip (jar uses zip) archive directory entries may be skipped.